# first client request not being served in sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

This is a simple iterative client-server program. Where the server prints out "Received request" on successful establishment of connection.

**server side**

```
#define LENGTH 256
#define SERV_PORT 4000  
#define LISTENQ 8
int main()
{
    int listenfd, connfd, n;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buf[LENGTH];
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;

    //creation of socket
    listenfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //creating socket address
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
    bind (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
   // printf("\nServer running.. waiting for connections");

   // listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

    for(; ;)
    {

        clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);
        printf("\nReceived request");
        //sleep(5);

    } 



    return 0;
}
```

**client side**

```
#define LENGTH 256
#define SERV_PORT 4000  

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent *hp; 
    char buff[256];

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;

    hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if(hp == 0)
    {
        perror("gethost by name failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    memcpy(&server.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    server.sin_port = htons(4000);

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("\nconnect failed");
        exit(1);
    }
       return 0;       
   }
```

When I run this multiple client-server code, the output for first client is different from the preceding clients. I need the first client to output like others. Can someone help?

When the first client establishes a connection with the server, the server doesn't output "Received request", where as, for the other clients do output "Received request".

Comment: Might be a simple artifact of STDOUT being buffered - stick a `\n` at the end of the printed line.

Comment: You need to restore the `listen()` call. Try some error handling. Try `fflush(stdout)`. NB when `accept()` returns, you haven't 'received a request' at all. You have received a *connection.*

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I tried. Doesn't work.  When the first client establishes a connection, a new line is outputted.

Comment: @EJP Can you be more specific? Or tell me what changes to make in the code?

Comment: `fflush()` after `printf()`. You aren't checking for errors on the `accept()` call, the `listen()` call, the `bind()` call, the `socket()` call, ... NB you aren't 'waiting for connections' until you're about to call `accept()`, and before you call `listen()` there can't ever *be* any connections. Don't mislead yourself like this with all these inaccurate messages.

Comment: Well, in your code it's at the beginning on the line, not at the end. Standard output is line-buffered by default, so until you end that line (or the internal library buffer gets full) nothing gets printed.

Comment: @EJP after restoring the listen() call it worked! I dint notice that it was in comments. Thanks for answering the dumbest ever question. _/\_

Comment: Client side -  `scanf("%s",buff);
send(sock, buff, strlen(buff), 0);`

Server side - `recv(connfd, buf, 2, 0);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("\n%s\n",buf);`

On the server side, along with the input supplied from client, previously stored content on 'buff' gets printed. Is it related to fflush()  you told earlier? @EJP

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov In this problem, i have tried placing '\n` at the end of line too. Can you help me witht the question asked above? I have been facing the same issue using recv and send or read and write too

Comment: That is a new question and not to be dealt with in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restore the `listen()` call. – EJP